# WX in Notification Center calls up Weather Channel in browser

Tags: notifications

I'm new to El Capitan, after using Snow Leopard for years.

Notification Center is nice, but clicking on a city in the weather list kicks me over to my browser and opens up a tab for that city at the Weather Channel website. WTH?

How do I prevent Notification Center from calling up my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the City Name will open the appropriate page from The Weather Channel in your default web browser. That is by design.

If you do not want to open the webpage and instead expand a panel showing the forecast for the city, click **anywhere** other than the city name (the blank space, the time, the temperature, etc.).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected it would be something simple.